# jQuery qTip and lightbox

Tags: jquery-plugins, lightbox, qtip

Does anyone have a solution for using jQuery qTip and lightbox at the same time.  It would seem that qTip hijacks the title tag in the anchor so that the title that's supposed to show underneath the enlarged image (via lightbox) is missing.  The qTips work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onRender callback of the Modal plugin you're using  to call the qtip() method instead. IF that doesn't work, try posting on the support forums here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/